# How to generate noise free data by training on clean data?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a problem where I have got two image data sets.

One is a clean image data set and the other one is the same data set but with noise mixed in it.

1) Is it possible to train a model on clean data (So, that it learns the characteristics of clean image) and then, When passed a noisy image it outputs the image data without noise (detects the noise, removes it and outputs the clean image data)?

2) Would GAN be useful in this case (If yes, How?)?

Comment: something like [pix2pix](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/) maybe

Comment: Maybe this paper [Noise2Noise: Learning Image Restoration without Clean Data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.04189.pdf) be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **denoising Autoencoder**. You input noisy images, and train the model to map them with their "clean counterpart".

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/denoising-autoencoders-explained-dbb82467fc2) you can find some info on denoising Autoencoders.

And you can find how to implement an Autoencoder in [TensorFlow 1.x](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow_3_Autoencoder_Dimensionality_Reduction.ipynb) and in [TensorFlow 2.0](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_04_Autoencoder_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.ipynb).

Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.